# Generate LACP traffic using scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, scapy, lacp

I need to generate STP and LACP traffics using scapy.
I've managed to do so for the STP:

```py
from scapy.all import STP
import scapy
from scapy.all import *
data='test'
a=Dot3(dst="01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd", src="08:17:35:51:29:2e")/LLC(dsap=0xaa, ssap=0xaa, ctrl=3)/SNAP(OUI=0x0c, code=0x010b)/STP(rootid=8406, portid=0x802e, pathcost=19, rootmac="2c:33:11:53:85:80",bridgeid=32982, bridgemac="08:17:35:51:29:00", bpdutype=128)/data
sendp(a,iface="eth2", count=200)
```

but I was blocked with the generation of the LACP traffic, I tried to follow [scapy.contrib.lacp](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.contrib.lacp.html#scapy.contrib.lacp.LACP) but I failed to understand how to work with it

Comment: can you give what you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In generate you should let scapy put the protocol types that link the layers.

```py
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import Ether, Dot3
from scapy.contrib.lacp import SlowProtocol, LACP
from scapy.layers.l2 import LLC, SNAP, STP


data='test'
pkt = Dot3(dst="01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd", src="08:17:35:51:29:2e") \
    / LLC(dsap=0xaa, ssap=0xaa, ctrl=3) \
    / SNAP(OUI=0x0c, code=0x010b) \
    / STP(rootid=8406, portid=0x802e, pathcost=19, rootmac="2c:33:11:53:85:80",bridgeid=32982, bridgemac="08:17:35:51:29:00", bpdutype=128) \
    / data
pkt.show2()
sendp(pkt, iface="eth2", count=200)

pkt = Ether() / SlowProtocol() / LACP()
pkt.show2()
sendp(pkt, iface="eth2", count=200)
```